# How can I prevent the automatic index in a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector

Following code

```
test <- c("key"=c(8, 5, 9))
```

Results in

```
key1 key2 key3
   8    5    9
```

However, I would like the output to be

```
key key key
  8   5   9
```

Is there a way to specify to the R vector that it should not add that automatic index? My current workaround is the following, which I call as soon as "test" is assigned

```
names(test) <- c(rep("key", length(test)))
```

Comment: `test <- setNames(c(8, 5, 9), rep("key", 3))` Or use a `list()`, for instance `test <- list("key"=c(8, 5, 9))`..

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the numbers afterwards

```
names(test) <- sub("\\d+", "", names(test))
```

-output

```
> test
key key key 
  8   5   9
```

Comment: It works, but I like the answer in the comment much better as only one statement is needed

Comment: @Davide I thought you already have created an object and want to modify it